# Немедленное закрытие вопросов на ru.SO, связанных с выполнением задания из учебников/курсов

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, вопросы, новые-участники

Вижу много постов, где новички в программировании, в частности, школьники, пытаются уговорить участников сообщества сделать какое-либо задание из учебника/курса/самоучителя за них.

Мне кажется, что такие вопросы нужно немедленно **закрывать**, так как приучают новичков думать *сайтом*, а не своей головой. О нашем сообществе уже давным-давно ходят "смешные картинки" о Copy-Paste from SO.

**Но** банить за это этих пользователей я не предлагаю. Некоторые будут продолжать биться головой об стену, некотрые, прочитая причину закрытия, пойдут гуглить. В принципе, вполне соответствует духу сообщества.

Comment: уже есть специальная причина закрытия _Сообщение содержит лишь текст задачи, в котором нет описания проблемы, либо вопрос чисто формален («как мне выполнить это задание»). Для повторного открытия вопроса, добавьте описание конкретной проблемы, поясните, что именно не получается, в чём вы видите проблему._

Comment: @Grundy там нет ответа ;)

Comment: Как мне кажется, это не верный подход. Причины опубликованы в оригинальном вопросе. Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с ними. Буду рад услышать ваши идеи на этот счет!

Comment: @FoggyFinder Это не вопрос, а публикация, выражение текущей позиции по данному вопросу.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky может есть смысл оформить в виде вопроса - ответа?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Копирование не даст возможность поддерживать релевантность информации.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky разве та публикация это строгое правило а не рекомендация/традиция?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Да, рекомендация.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky в таком случае почему бы не вынести вопрос на обсуждение (что делать с такими вопросами), а не закрывать как дубликат?